# Checking to see if two integer inputs are within range - java

Tags: java, variables, exception, error-handling, integer

I want to check if two integer inputs are within range and legit. The following code is what I've come up with.

The problem is that when I check to see if the first input is within range, it doesn't pop up with an error (when incorrect) until I've entered the second input whether that's correct or not. And when the error comes up, it just prints the error as well as an empty line which waits for a user input (for no apparent reason); in which I enter anything and hit "enter" then the program runs again (continues loop) asking for the user to input values again until it's correct.

This problem doesn't occur when I input a character. The error for input mismatch works perfectly. It prints the error and then runs the program again, asking for the user to input values again until it's legit.

How can I get it to check the first input to see if it's within range and output an error if incorrect straight after the user hits enter, then checks the second input and does the same?

Does this make sense?

```
public String totalTime(){

    flag = 1;

    do{
        try{
            System.out.print("Enter a starting destination: ");
            int choice1 = user_input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter a final desination: ");
            int choice2 = user_input.nextInt();

            if( (choice1 >= 1 && choice1 <= 5) && (choice2 >= 1 && choice2 <= 5) ){
                switch(choice1){

                    case 1: if (choice2 == 2){hour = 0; minutes = 10;} else if (choice2 == 3){hour = 0; minutes = 30;} else if (choice2 == 4) {hour = 1; minutes = 10;} else if (choice2 == 5) {hour = 1; minutes = 5;} break;
                    case 2: if (choice2 == 1){hour = 0; minutes = 10;} else if (choice2 == 3){hour = 0; minutes = 25;} else if (choice2 == 4) {hour = 1; minutes = 0;} else if (choice2 == 5) {hour = 0; minutes = 15;} break;
                    case 3: if (choice2 == 1){hour = 0; minutes = 48;} else if (choice2 == 2){hour = 0; minutes = 23;} else if (choice2 == 4) {hour = 0; minutes = 45;} else if (choice2 == 5) {hour = 0; minutes = 12;}break;
                    case 4: if (choice2 == 1){hour = 1; minutes = 5;} else if (choice2 == 2){hour = 1; minutes = 0;} else if (choice2 == 3) {hour = 0; minutes = 45;} else if (choice2 == 5) {hour = 0; minutes = 40;}break;
                    case 5: if (choice2 == 1){hour = 0; minutes = 30;} else if (choice2 == 2){hour = 0; minutes = 15;} else if (choice2 == 3) {hour = 0; minutes = 10;} else if (choice2 == 4) {hour = 0; minutes = 40;}break;
                    default: System.out.println("There is no such route");

                }
                flag = 2;
            }
            else if (choice1 < 1 || choice1 > 5 || choice2 < 1 || choice2 > 5){
                throw new NumberFormatException("Integer is out of range.");
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){

            System.out.println("The number is not between 1 and 5. Try again.");
            System.out.println();
            user_input.next(); //removes leftover stuff from input buffer


        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){

            System.out.println("This is not an integer. Try again.");
            System.out.println();
            user_input.next(); //removes leftover stuff from input buffer

        }
    }while (flag == 1);
    return ("The total time is " + hour + " hours and " + minutes + " minutes");
}
```

Comment: You mean in the catch blocks?

Comment: OK so user_input.nextLine(); in the catch blocks stops the random empty line after error pops up. But I'm still wondering how to print error after each input...

Comment: You ask for the first input, and then, without checking whether it's right or wrong, you ask for the second input. Only after that do you check if the values are in range. Your program is doing exactly what you have asked it to.

Answer (score 0):

To validate and re-ask for user input, you need to ask for the input in a while loop and not leave the loop till the input is valid.

So immediately after asking for the first input, you can do something like

```
System.out.println("Enter a starting destination: ");
        int choice1 = user_input.nextInt();

while(choice1 < 1 || choice1 > 5) {
  System.out.println("Invalid Input");
  if(user_input.hasNextInt())
      choice1 = user_input.nextInt();
  else
      user_input.next();
}

System.out.println("Enter a final desination: ");
        int choice2 = user_input.nextInt();

while(choice2 < 1 || choice2 > 5 || choice2 == choice1) {
  System.out.println("Invalid Input");
  if(user_input.hasNextInt())
      choice2 = user_input.nextInt();
  else
      user_input.next();
}
```

This way also avoids throwing needless errors that are used only to control program flow (can be very very difficult to read)